# Secure MongoDB Over Public Internet

Tags: node.js, mongodb

With the recent attacks on Mongo databases, I've seen many guides on how to password-protect your database. I've gone through each guide and I've set up a 'superAdmin' with root role and another basicAdmin with read/write privileges. I reboot mongo using

```
mongo --auth
```

and authenticate using my superAdmin login, however this causes problems for my site which uses this db. When I boot my Node app, I can't access any pages as it cannot connect to the database because it has auth enabled. If in my config/database.js file I have:

```
module.exports = {
    'database': 'mongodb://myWebsite.com/myDatabase'
};
```

How can I allow my site to access my MongoDB and read/write as users signup but also restrict any ransomware group from just walking in and dropping every collection over and over?

Comment: Just to be clear you want to know how to secure mongoDb right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three main methods that you can use to protect your database.

### Username and password

This is the simpler one. As you have mentioned that you have already secured the server using password, you can simply connect to database using mongoose as

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database');
```

I might recommend here that you change the default port of mongoDb to something else. Changing port can be found in file `/etc/mongodb.conf`.

### Bind to private ip and use firewall

Again refering to file `/etc/mongodb.conf` change `bind_ip` to local ip of your network. Most of the services do provide that. Also better to setup firewall for the same. Simple firewall that you can use is [UFW](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall). Only allow traffic from servers that you are using. This method might not be effective if you are using shared vpn service.

### SSH tunnel to access database

This is far most the most reliable method and i would recommend you to use this with the last method. Here is how this works. Set `bind_ip` to `127.0.0.1`. Let us assume that you are running port on **5000**. In order to set up a tunnel use

```
ssh \
-L 4000:localhost:5000 \
-i ~/.ssh/key \
<username>@mongo_db_ip
```

Remember to add your `ssh` key in instance running mongodb database. The above command should be issued on server that is running nodejs. **5000** as mentioned is the remove port and **4000** is the local port that you need to connect to on mongodb. So your command in mongoose to connect to database would be

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:4000/<database>');
```

#### Summary

As you can see in almost all the steps i have focused on setting up a firewall which is very important.

Also username and passwords should be avoided and it is better to use `ssh keys`. From practical experience they also reduce a lot of burden while you are scaling up your service.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: @mrneeson glad i could help you out :)